# How to get total salary from each month from date?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-dates

Given that image below, B is date in format [month/day/year] and salary.

From that date, can we total up salary from specific month in yellow table?

For instance, we want the total number of salary from white table, how to do it without adding one by one?

I suspected that we use something like, (if the month of the date is january, take that value of the salary).

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `query()`, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  query( 
    { eomonth(B2:B, -1) + 1, C2:C },
    "select Col1, sum(Col2) 
     where Col1 is not null 
     group by Col1 
     label Col1 'month' 
     format Col1 'mmmm yyyy' ", 
   1 
  ) 
)
```

See [query()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093343), [eomonth()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093044) and [{ array expressions }](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276).